# R data.table: how to change each preceding 0 into a 1 within a column?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have the following R data.table, which is composed of only one column:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(first_column = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0))

> DT
    first_column
 1:            0
 2:            0
 3:            0
 4:            1
 5:            1
 6:            1
 7:            0
 8:            0
 9:            1
10:            1
11:            0
12:            0
13:            0
14:            0
15:            1
16:            1
17:            1
18:            1
19:            1
20:            0
21:            0
...          ...
```

The binary column `first_column` is composed of "clusters" of consecutive ones.

I would like to turn each preceding 0 for each cluster and turn this into a 1. Somehow, one checks for a `1`, and then change the preceding 0 into 1.

EDIT: To be more clear, the pattern `0001110011000011111...` would become `0011110111000111111...`

Comment: `DT[, v := do.call(pmax, shift(first_column, 0:1, type="lead", fill=0))]`, I guess.

Comment: Or `DT[DT[first_column==1, which=TRUE]-1L, first_column := 1 ]`

Comment: @Frank The second makes a good deal of sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the OP correctly, he wants to turn any occurence of the sub-sequence `0,1` into `1,1`:

```
DT <- data.table(first_column = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0))

DT[first_column == 0 & shift(first_column, type = "lead") == 1, first_column := 1]

DT[, first_column]
# [1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

At the expense of implicit type conversions from `double` to `logical`, this can be written more concisely as:

```
DT <- data.table(first_column = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0))

DT[!first_column & shift(first_column, type = "lead"), first_column := 1]
DT[, first_column]
# [1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

Here, the fact is used that `0` is treated as `FALSE` and any number unequal to `0` as `TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using `diff`:

```
DT$first_column[diff(DT$first_column)==1] <- 1

    # first_column
 # 1:            0
 # 2:            0
 # 3:            1
 # 4:            1
 # 5:            1
 # 6:            1
 # 7:            0
 # 8:            1
 # 9:            1
# 10:            1
# 11:            0
# 12:            0
# 13:            0
# 14:            1
# 15:            1
# 16:            1
# 17:            1
# 18:            1
# 19:            1
# 20:            0
# 21:            0
    # first_column
```

Basically `diff` will output `1` wherever a `1` is preceded by a `0`.

Answer (score 2):

This will replace the final value of each 0/1 "group" with a 1, which will be redundant for the 1 groups, but what you want to accomplish for the 0s (if I read your question correctly).

```
DT[, c(head(first_column, -1), 1), by=rleid(first_column)]
```

`rleid` is used to group adjacent 0s and 1s and `head` with -1 keeps all but the final element. Or even better, you can use `replace` as @Frank suggests, like this

```
DT[, replace(first_column, .N, 1), by=rleid(first_column)]
```

where `.N` is used to specify the final row in the group. Both of these return

```
    rleid V1
 1:     1  0
 2:     1  0
 3:     1  1
 4:     2  1
 5:     2  1
 6:     2  1
 7:     3  0
 8:     3  1
 9:     4  1
10:     4  1
11:     5  0
12:     5  0
13:     5  0
14:     5  1
15:     6  1
16:     6  1
17:     6  1
18:     6  1
19:     6  1
20:     7  0
21:     7  1
    rleid V1
```

---

These solutions (incorrectly) fill in the final observation with a 1. One way to avoid this is to add a check before filling in the values.

```
DT[, if(.I[.N] < nrow(DT)) replace(first_column, .N, 1) else first_column,
   by=rleid(first_column)]
```

Here, `.I[.N] < nrow(DT)` returns TRUE for every group except the final group. The final observation of this group is left "as is."

Comment: `c(head(x, -1), 1)` is `replace(x, .N, 1)`, I guess. Btw, wrong output for the final row, eh.

Comment: Oh neat. I didn't think of `replace` in this context.

Comment: I guess you didn't see the edit to my comment, but your output is not right. Row 21 should have zero still.